# how to join two string columns into one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
________________
| authors       |
|name  | surname|
|------|--------|
|Jeff  | Lindsay|
|George| Martin |
|______|________|
```

and I need to join these two columns into a one with a space between them. I tried something like this

```
SELECT (name + ', ' + surname) AS Name
FROM authors
```

but it returns me this:

```
 ________________
|    name       |
|      0        |
|      0        |
|_______________|
```

How to I join these two together so I have a full name?

Comment: Concat works: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: -1: you did not even [try](https://www.google.com/#q=mysql+join+two+strings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mysql its called [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
select concat(name,' ',surname) as fullname
from author
```

Comment: sirname should only be used when referring to superior officers

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT concat_ws(" ",first_name,last_name) FROM users
```

in concat_ws you have to define separator in start and followed by n no of fields which you want to separate